# Validate Google Analytics ID

Tags: google-analytics

Is there any way to check if Google Analytics Website property ID (ga_id) is valid? If there is a website with the provided ID and if the website is the correct one?
I've searched on the internet but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/v3/mgmtPython.html#webproperties The answer is "Use oauth2".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:
http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113500